# querying and convert to array of objects

Tags: javascript, php, json

i need to query and convert rows of code and location to a array of objects in javacript, but im having some issues, could someone help me.

My code here:

```
$sql = "SELECT code, city_name FROM airports";
$consulta = mysql_query($sql);

while($mostrar = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
     $locals[] = $mostrar['code'] . " ".$mostrar['city_name'];
}


?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var allLocations = <?php echo json_encode($locals); ?>;
</script>
```

What im trying to achive is something like:

```
[
    {value:"code", label:"name"},
    {value:"code", label:"name"},
...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line 
`$locals[] = $mostrar['code'] . " ".$mostrar['city_name'];`
to 
`$locals[] = array("value"=> $mostrar['code'], "label" => $mostrar['city_name']);`.

So, use `json_encode($locals)` to show as Json.

Comment: Hello Rafael, i did it exatlly you told, but for some reason, there are some words that uses accentuation like (~,^´..), that is outputting some words like "D\u00e9dougou", do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Hi Pedro, it's about encode, your resulto output is like a UTF8, check this [uft8 char site](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) and do a search for this `U+00E9`, you  will find a "é" char. It's normal.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change

```
while($mostrar = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
     $locals[] = $mostrar['code'] . " ".$mostrar['city_name'];
}
```

to

```
while($mostrar = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
     $locals[] = array("value"=> $mostrar['code'], "label" => $mostrar['city_name']);
}
```

So instead of just adding each row as a string, you add them as an array with name/value pairing.